# At what temperatures did various atomic and subatomic particles begin to form?

Tags: big-bang

I've been simulating the expansion of the universe using the Friedmann Equation and some numerical integration in python.

I've been able to calculate the temperature of the universe by dividing the current temperature (2.73K) by the scale factor. Is this the correct way of calculating the temperature?

I've been looking for a source, but without success of at which temperatures various types of particles can exist?

I'm also curious if there's any other interesting things which can be discovered using this equation?

Comment: It seems a bit vague...

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the timeline](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/timlin.html) in the big bang model versus temperature and the generation of particles depicted.

[image: bbtime]

Where they depict the strong interaction. quarks and gluons in a plasma can exist. In the region up to the weak  symmetry breaking , they will be zero mass, on the group structure of the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model). After mass confinement there will be protons and neutrons. A range of temperatures is seen, because it is statistical models. There are references whence the plot is built up.

Comment: Is it the Fermi temperature or normal "heat" temperature? Due to symmetry, as well as the entropy increase, the initial heat temperature of the universe must be the absolute zero. Assuming initially the universe is all radiation (a big assumption), there would be no reason for the Fermi temperature to be above zero either. What is the reason for a high temperature, Fermi or normal, before any fermions are formed?

Comment: It is  extrapolation to the place where  the classical singularity would be, where it is replaced by the quantum mechanical fuzziness, and then the  quantum mechanical inflation. temperature is the usual radiation and /or kinetic energy statistical definition. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)